# jenkins to get build number from 2 different jobs

Tags: jenkins

Right now I use "Run" parameter in a job that retrieves last successful build of another job to this job. This parameter gives me a dropdown of all last successful builds and I can manually choose any build and use it in my current job. But now I want to extend it to choose last successful build from 2 different jobs i.e. my current job should be able to see all successful builds in 2 different jobs and be able to choose any job of the choice. How do i do this in Jenkins. (Note: I do not want 2 different Run parameters- one for each job. It should be a single choice)